# Find and Assign Values to columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame of Movie genres of `str` type

```
    genre
0   8.3/10Family Action & Adventure ...More Genres...
1   8.6/10Fantasy Anime ...More GenresFantasyAnime...
2   8.7/10Science-Fiction Action & Adventure Rated...
3   8.1/10Family Action & Adventure ...More Genres...
4   8.4/10Science-Fiction Family ...More GenresSci..
```

and I'd like to filter out the list of genres
 `genres = ['Family', 'Action & Adventure', 'Fantasy']` into a new column

```
    genre
0   Family, Action & Adventure
1   Fantasy, Anime
2   Science-Fiction, Action & Adventure
3   Family Action, Adventure
4   Science-Fiction, Family
```

Please Advise.

Comment: Instead of `...More Genres...` please provide a reproducible dataset where people can do something and test also their code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with values of list joined by `|` for regex `or` and then [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), for remove duplicates is use convert lists to sets by `.apply(set)`:

```
df['genre'] = df['genre'].str.findall('|'.join(genres)).apply(set).str.join(',')
```

Comment: Gets most of the job done, but for some reason it returns the same value twice

Comment: For example if `Family` is found it returns `Family,Family`

Comment: @Luke - yop, reason are possible duplicates, if use `.apply(set)` remove dupes